# Copy AMI from one AWS account to another AWS account using boto

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-ami

I did some RnD but didn't find any answer or hint on this topic. Can anyone give an hint or answer if it is possible to copy AMI from one AWS account to another using boto.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot directly copy the AMI from one account to another but can share the AMI with other account and then copy the image in second account locally. Here is how:

```
# Copying image from src_account to dest_account
SRC_ACCOUNT_ID = '111111'
DEST_ACCOUNT_ID = '222222'
IMAGE_ID = '333333'
SRC_REGION = 'us-west-1'
DEST_REGION = 'us-east-1'

# Create CrossAccountole Role in src_account which will give permission to operations in the acount
sts = boto3.client('sts')
credentials = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::'+SRC_ACCOUNT_ID +':role/CrossAccountRole',
    RoleSessionName="RoleSession1"
)['Credentials']
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=SRC_REGION,
    aws_access_key_id = credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token = credentials['SessionToken']
)

# Access the image that needs to be copied
image = ec2.Image(IMAGE_ID)

# Share the image with the destination account
image.modify_attribute(
    ImageId = image.id,
    Attribute = 'launchPermission',
    OperationType = 'add',
    LaunchPermission = {
        'Add' : [{ 'UserId': DEST_ACCOUNT_ID }]
    }
)

# We have to now share the snapshots associated with the AMI so it can be copied
devices = image.block_device_mappings
for device in devices:
    if 'Ebs' in device:
        snapshot_id = device["Ebs"]["SnapshotId"]
        snapshot = ec2.Snapshot(snapshot_id)
        snapshot.modify_attribute(
            Attribute = 'createVolumePermission',
            CreateVolumePermission = {
                'Add' : [{ 'UserId': DEST_ACCOUNT_ID }]
            },
            OperationType = 'add',
        )

# Access destination account so we can now copy the image
credentials = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::'+DEST_ACCOUNT_ID+':role/CrossAccountRole',
    RoleSessionName="RoleSession1"
)['Credentials']

# Copy image to failover regions
ec2fra = boto3.client('ec2', DEST_REGION,
    aws_access_key_id = credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token = credentials['SessionToken']
)

# Copy the shared AMI to dest region
ec2fra.copy_image(
    Name = 'MY_COPIED_IMAGE_FROM_OTHER_ACCOUNT',
    SourceImageId = image.id,
    SourceRegion = SRC_REGION
)
```

There it is, simple :)

Read about commands [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html)

Comment: Thank you bro u saved my time really !

Comment: @vikramaditya234, Could you please paste the code for copying the s3 bucket particular files from one account to another account?

Comment: @Mia there are 2 ways to copy, one is to copy the files to the local system: `aws s3 cp s3://SRC_BUCKET/FILE <LOCAL_PATH>` and then to destination bucket `aws s3 cp <LOCAL_PATH> s3://DEST_BUCKET/FILE`. Second is to sync files between the buckets `aws s3 sync s3://SRC_BUCKET s3://DEST_BUCKET`. If this is ongoing job, you can also set up bucket replication, so new files and updates to old files will be automatically copied to the destination buckets. For all these to work you need to update the permission of the bucket to accept files from cross account

Comment: @vikramaditya234, Thanks for your reply. Now i have a requirement that I need to copy the csv only from the production account to the client account. How can i achieve this using code? any suggestion

Comment: @mia you can use `--include` argument for this, please check the AWS S3 CLI document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/

Answer (score 2):

You could share the AMI from one account to another. Try this:

[Sharing an AMI with Specific AWS Accounts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html)

Does that do what you want it to do?

Here it is in [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_image_attribute).

After sharing the image, perhaps then you can copy it with [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.copy_image).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to copy the AMI, but you can share it as @byumark said. Sharing is pretty easy with boto3. I wouldn't use the client like he did, I would use the [resource.](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#image)

Now if dealing with encrypted AMI's its a bit trickier. You need to allow access to the CMK used for the encryption, share the snapshot its self not the ami. Then copy the snapshot and when copying set encryption again to make sure its encrypted with the target account default KMS key.